# .htaccess define url part as a variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Url what I have:

```
example.com/ru/support

RewriteRule ^\w{2}/support index.php?route=support/support&lang=$ [L]
```

how I can have `w{2}` this part in url as a param `&lang=$` . Reaally I dont understand how to define url part in `RewriteRule` as a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex terms, you need to "capture" the stuff you want to later use in a "backreference".

```
RewriteRule ^(\w{2})/support index.php?route=support/support&lang=$1 [L]
```

$1 is just the first thing captured in ()